# How to activate C# 10 features Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, c#-10.0

I try to use the newest C# 10 features in Visual Studio 2022 Preview 3. The compiler does not recognize the new keywords required or field. global using seems to work.

```
public required string Name { get; init; }
public DateTime HiredDate{ get; init => field = value.Date(); }
```

Null parameter checking doesn't compile:

```
public void NullParameterCheck(string arg!!) { ... }
```

I also tried to set the language version to preview in the .csproj:

```
<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
```

Is there any setting I missed?

Comment: Now that C# 10 is released, we know that these cool features have been postponed to a later version.

Answer (score 7):

Finally I found part of the solution. I have to add

```
<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
<EnablePreviewFeatures>true</EnablePreviewFeatures>
```

to the .csproj file. Null parameter checks work, but not required and field.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I use in .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    <EnablePreviewFeatures>true</EnablePreviewFeatures>
    <GenerateRequiresPreviewFeaturesAttribute>true</GenerateRequiresPreviewFeaturesAttribute>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>
```